# Moving items in a Firebase Array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, firebase, synchronization, angularfire

I have been playing around with the firebase API and have hit a bit of a wall.

The problem is that I'm trying to move an item up or down an array but can't seem to figure out how to do this in the Firebase API.

Here is my controller

```
angular.module('aceTrainingApp')
  .controller('AdminController',['$scope','FirebaseService', function ($scope, FirebaseService) {

    $scope.posts = FirebaseService.getPosts();
    $scope.localPosts = $scope.posts; //is this Right??
    $scope.newPost = {name: '', body: ''};

        $scope.remove = function (id) {
            FirebaseService.removePost(id);
        };

        $scope.updatePost = function (id) {
            FirebaseService.updatePost(id);
            $scope.newPost = {name: '', body: ''};
        };

        $scope.addPost = function() {
            FirebaseService.addPost(angular.copy($scope.newPost));
        };

//only trying to get moveDown working first
//            $scope.moveUp = function(post) {
//            var crntPos = $scope.posts.indexOf(post);
//           if (crntPos > 0) {
//                $scope.posts.splice(crntPos, 1);
//                $scope.posts.splice(crntPos - 1, 0, post);
//            }
//        };

    $scope.moveDown = function(post) {
        var crntPos = $scope.localPosts.indexOf(post);
        if (crntPos < $scope.localPosts.length) {
            $scope.localPosts.splice(crntPos, 1);
            $scope.localPosts.splice(crntPos + 1, 0, post);
            FirebaseService.updateAllPosts($scope.localPosts);
        }
    };
  }]);
```

And here is the service

```
angular.module('aceTrainingApp').factory('FirebaseService', [ '$firebase', function($firebase){

var ref = new Firebase('https://acetrainingsolutions.firebaseio.com/');
var posts = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

var getPosts = function(){
    return posts;
};

var removePost = function(id){
    posts.$remove(id);
};

var updatePost = function(post){
    posts.$save(post);
};



var addPost = function(index){
    posts.$add(index);
};

return {
    getPosts: getPosts,
    removePost: removePost,
    updatePost: updatePost,
    addPost: addPost
};
}]);
```

HTML

```
    <li ng-repeat="post in localPosts track by $index">
        <input type="text" ng-model="post.name" ng-blur="updatePost($index)">
        <input type="text" ng-model="post.body" ng-blur="updatePost($index)">
        <button type="button" class="close space" ng-click="moveDown(post)">&DownArrow;</button>
        <button type="button" class="close space" ng-click="moveUp(post)">&UpArrow;</button>
        <button type="button" class="close space" ng-click="remove($index)">&times;</button>
    </li>
```

The problem is that the splice method only works on the view as mentioned in the Firebase docs. Can someone help me fix the moveUp and moveDown functions?

Cheers

Comment: are multiple clients going to be writing to this array at the same time?

Comment: no not really, this functionality is implemented in an admin page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that because my array contained objects with keys containing '$', the update method wouldn't work. The update method was also incorrect.

FirebaseService

```
    var updatePost = function(id){
    posts.$save(id);
};

var updateAllPosts = function(posts){
    ref.set(posts);
};
```

AdminController

```
        $scope.moveDown = function(post) {
        var localPosts = [];
        var crntPos = $scope.posts.indexOf(post);
        if (crntPos < $scope.posts.length) {
            $scope.posts.splice(crntPos, 1);
            $scope.posts.splice(crntPos + 1, 0, post);

            for(var i = 0; i < $scope.posts.length; i++){
                var obj = {
                    name: $scope.posts[i].name,
                    body: $scope.posts[i].body
                };
                localPosts.push(obj);
            }
            FirebaseService.updateAllPosts(localPosts);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have read the docs and seen the useful blog post here: 
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase
https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

As you don't have to worry about multiple clients writing data at the same time then this makes life a little easier.

I'm sure the good folks at Firebase could improve on this answer but my suggestion would be to manage things client-side and then write the whole array back to Firebase at the appropriate time (whether that's on a change or when a user clicks save is up to you). Firebase will detect that it's an array you're writing and add indexes as keys anyway with 0 being first, 1 second and so on. This way you can maintain order.

Keep your Firebase posts

```
$scope.posts = FirebaseService.getPosts();
```

and have a local array of posts too which you can then write back to Firebase

```
$scope.localPosts = [];
```

Then work on the localPosts using `Splice` etc.

When you're ready, write the `localPosts` back to Firebase. This approach worked for me but I'm not sure if it's great advice I'm giving you so apologies in advance if Firebase themselves say it's a "no-no"

Comment: Thanks for that Tommy, I think I understand what your saying. Still having a little difficulty though. Would my moveDown method become something like this?
`$scope.moveDown = function(post) {

            $scope.localPosts = $scope.posts;
            var crntPos = $scope.localPosts.indexOf(post);
            if (crntPos < $scope.localPosts.length) {
                $scope.localPosts.splice(crntPos, 1);
                $scope.localPosts.splice(crntPos + 1, 0, post);
            }
   FirebaseService.updatePost($scope.localPosts);
};
`AND
`updatePost = function(posts){
posts.$set(posts);
};`

Comment: Yeah this is on the right lines - have a go a let me know if you're getting any errors.

Comment: okay, so my updatePost method now looks like this
`    var updatePost = function(position, post){
        ref.child(position.toString()).set(post)
    };
`
However, I seem to be getting this error which is telling me im using set incorrectly.
Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument  contains an invalid key ($id) in property '1'.  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"
    at Error (native)

Comment: Yeah I thought this might happen so you're def going in the same direction as me. You need to tell Angular to not set extra values in the array - use `ng-repeat="post as localPosts as $index"` I think - just checking now

Comment: Sorry `track by $index` so in your view where you show your local posts use something like: `ng-repeat="post as localPosts track by $index"`

Comment: Hmm, still doesn't seem to work. Still getting all the Angular Guff inside the ng-repeat. I've updated the question with my changes, maybe you can spot something i'm doing wrong

Comment: Don't set localPosts as equal to the Firebase array as you get the "guff" from that too. Just make your own "clean" array by reading from one and writing to another with just the bits you want. I'm sorry I haven't got any code as I deleted all my code recently as I changed direction with my project.

Comment: thanks a lot, finally got it with your pointers. I loop through $scope.posts and then create an object based on the name and body properties. I then push this array to localPosts and run my update method :) Can't upvote though because of my rep is < 15

Comment: Will be interesting to see what Firebase have to say.